# Does Friedel-Crafts reaction fail with benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I know that Friedel-Crafts reaction  (either alkylation or acylation) fails with phenol and aniline, due to formation of a coordinate bond between Lewis acid catalyst and the lone pair of the respective functional group.

But I have read that even benzoic acid fails to undergo this reaction. I couldn't think of a reason for this. Can anyone explain why is it so?

Comment: Still the same reason.

Comment: I personally performed Friedle-Crafts acilation on 4-hydroxy-[2,2]-paraciclphane  (a kind of phenol) using TiCl4 and AcCl (or TiCl4 and (COCl)2). TiCl4, however, is required in slight excess to equimole amount in this reaction.

Comment: @Mithoron I did fell like that but is benzoic acid 'basic' enough to get coordinated?

Comment: Is quite nucleophilic

Comment: @Mithoron Through which 'O' atom does it get coordinated to the catalyst.

Comment: Hi, does phenol really behaves as aniline when treated with Lewis acid (Friedel-Crafts reactions), and when treated with Bronsted acid (e.g. during nitration and sulphonation)? Many websites just say only aniline acts as Lewis & Bronsted base

Answer (score 5):

It could be that $\ce{-COOH}$ group is electron withdrawing hence there is an increased electron density in $\ce{-COOH}$ group due to -R resonating effect of electron from benzene ring.

Since friedel craft catalyst is a Lewis acid (electron deficient) the catalyst (anhydrous $\ce{AlCl3}$) reacts with electron rich COOH group of benzoic acid and gets bonded.

Comment: Hi, abhishek. Did you reach a conclusion in your answer? You have stated *two* possibilities - a deactivated ring due to $-R$, and a bond formed by $\ce{-COOH}$ with the Lewis acid - for FC reaction to not happen. Which one of these is your answer _exactly_? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think Friedel Craft reaction with Benzoic acid fails because the Benzene ring is deactivated. Here electrophile is Carbocation  which is a weak electrophile. So the necessity for Friedel-Craft reaction is activated Benzene ring.

Comment: I don't get it when you say "C+ is a weak electrophile". A carbocation? I don't think that's a weak electrophile. Anyway, do you mean that all mono-substituted benzene rings with deactivating groups (i.e., atleast as strongly deactivated as benzoic acid) fail to give Friedel- Crafts reactions.

Comment: I think yes. And also I am doubtful whether carbocation is a strong electrophile.

Comment: @AadityaJoshi Carbocations are pretty good electrophiles. The more important factor here is the coordination of the lewis acid to the carboxylic acid group.

Comment: @bon Yes, now I think it is so but through which of the two oxygen atoms does benzoic acid coordinate to lewis acid?

Comment: @user104014 Probably the carbonyl oxygen but I'm not entirely sure.