# Why does benzoate show Friedel Crafts alkylation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Why does benzoate show Friedel Crafts alkylation?

I know that benzoic acid does not show Friedel Crafts alkylation because the Lewis acid forms a bond with the lone pair of oxygen itself. So, shouldn't the same happen with benzoate as well? The oxygen in benzoate has a negative charge, which should make bond formation with the Lewis acid even easier. But my book states that it will show Friedel Crafts alkylation.

Comment: Related [question on Chem.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44193/does-friedel-crafts-reaction-fail-with-benzoic-acid) but it didn't get answered conclusively.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thank you for the link but it increased my confusion even more. All the reasons due to which benzoic acid does not show Friedal Crafts should be valid with benzoate also. But they aren't.